# Ember 2 performances, is javascript event delegation in #each automagically? How to coalesce similar listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm reading a lot (for study) about "**Event delegation**" and also because in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udix3GZouik (minute 22:28) Alex Blom talks about: "*Coalesce similar listeners*" for performance reasons.

[image]

My question is: is Ember automagically performing about this problem?

If I have an `#each` with many div in it how to coalesce listeners on the parent div? **Does Ember do it in my place?**

https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 0):

Interesting here is the difference between *classic* actions and closure actions. First lets show them both:

**classic action**

```
<button {{action 'foo'}}>foo</button>
```

**closure action**

```
<button onclick={{action 'foo'}}>foo</button>
```

These two almost behave identical, however are *very* different. The classic action does *not attach an event listener* on the element itself. Instead the `click` event will bubble up to the ember root element, and there ember will know which action to call. So for classic actions ember will coalesce listeners on the ember root div. This is why you can only use a list of predefined events, for which listeners are attached to the root div.

However closure actions are just a simple closure function directly attached to the element listener. So here ember will do much less magic, but attach a separate listener for each `onclick=`.

However interesting here is that ember is switching towards closure actions for better developer experience. So this suggests that ember developers think, that this is not a big performance concern (anymore).

In my experience reducing the amount of listeners is not a good way for performance improvement. A few more listeners will not have a dramatic effect on the performance, but give you far better developer and debugging experience. So for a list over half a dozen items this is not really a concern. Real problems come with enormous amounts of listeners, only happening if you render something like very long lists, far larger then the viewport. In theese cases its a much better idea to reduce DOM, and not just listeners.
Here I would recommend tools like [vertical-collection](https://github.com/html-next/vertical-collection) and [smoke and mirrors (SAM)](https://github.com/runspired/smoke-and-mirrors)

Comment: I respect you very much (you have a fabulous experience and are always very helpful), I perfectly understand your point of view, but do not you think that even that dozen less events on a smartphone make the difference?

Comment: I would love to see some benchmarks with ember here! [This is interesting](https://jsperf.com/jquery-event-delegation/5). But I think usually there are always other things to optimize first. Also I'm not sure if actually the event listeners are slow, or finding the DOM nodes. Because the later is something we don't have to do with glimmer. And I don't see any reason why event listeners should be slow.